# When trying to get last date of next month getting last date of next month of next year in java

Tags: java, datetime, date

Trying to run this code it was working perfectly fine till `OCT` but in `NOV` it is like 
`firstdate 2019-12-01 & lastdate  2020-12-31`

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();         
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        String date;    
        calendar.set(Calendar.DATE,calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        Date nextMonthFirstDay = calendar.getTime();
        date=new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd").format(nextMonthFirstDay).toLowerCase();
        System.out.println("firstdate "+ date);

        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        Date nextMonthLastDay = calendar.getTime();
        date=new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd").format(nextMonthLastDay).toLowerCase();
        System.out.println("lastdate  "+date);

    }
}
```

I don't know why it is showing like this..
Is it a fault or bug in java ?

Comment: try this ``  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, ANY_MONTH);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, ANY_YEAR);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);// This is necessary to get proper results
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE));
    cal.getTime();``

Comment: yup still for nov not working working till oct

Answer (score 6):

Change your date format to **yyyy-MM-dd** *(notice lowercase for year)*

They both represent a year but **yyyy** represents the calendar year while **YYYY** represents the year of the week.

So something like...

```
date=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(nextMonthLastDay).toLowerCase();
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to already have got an answer that works, however, here is one that uses the modern datetime API `java.time` and is *s little* more readable than the way you are calculating the first and last day of the next month based on today:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // base is today
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    /*
     * create a LocalDate from 
     * - the year of next month (may be different)
     * - the current month plus 1 and 
     * - the first day
     * ——> first day of next month
     */
    LocalDate firstDayOfNextMonth = LocalDate.of(
            today.plusMonths(1).getYear(),
            today.getMonth().plus(1),
            1);
    /*
     * create a LocalDate from 
     * - the first day of next month (just created above)
     * - add a month and
     * - subtract one day
     * ——> last day of next month
     */
    LocalDate lastDayOfNextMonth = firstDayOfNextMonth.plusMonths(1).minusDays(1);

    // print the results
    System.out.println("first date of upcoming month:\t"
                        + firstDayOfNextMonth.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE));
    System.out.println("last date of upcoming month:\t"
                        + lastDayOfNextMonth.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE));
}
```

Don't be misled by the formatting, there are significantly fewer lines of code and their output is

```
first date of upcoming month:   2019-12-01
last date of upcoming month:    2019-12-31
```

Comment: Bro its giving last day of next month but last year! Anyway thanks

Comment: @ShantanuKhond corrected, now it does what it is supposed to, I think.

Comment: @ShantanuKhond I found another flaw and have corrected it, the first day of next month wasn't always correct because I took the year of `today`, but it has to be the year of next month, which may be different fromt today's date.